# Works in codepen but not in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, codepen

I'm trying to get this animated svg tree to work in Wordpress. It works fine in codepen, but not at all in a Wordpress page on my localhost.

Can anyone see what is missing/wrong? In the page source code the javascript files are loading.

[svg tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRw7D.png)

```js
var svg = $("#svg-container");
svg.children().find("path:not(.except)").click(function(e) {
  $("#Layer_1 path").removeAttr("style");
  $this = $(this);
  var bbox = this.getBBox();
  var centreX = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
  var centreY = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
  $this.css("transform-origin", centreX + 'px ' + centreY + 'px');
  $this.css("transform", "scale(4)");
  $this.css("stroke", "");
  $this.css("fill", "");
  this.parentElement.appendChild(this);
})
```

```css
#svg-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#svg-container svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Amaranth";
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth');
}
```

```html
<div id="svg-container">
  <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    < ![CDATA[

    ]] >
  </script>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1247.24px" height="1360.63px" viewBox="0 0 1800 1400" enable-background="new 0 0 1247.24 1360.63" xml:space="preserve">
  
<g>
<font>
  <font-face font-family="Amaranth">
    <font-face-src>
      <font-face-uri xlink:href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth" />
    </font-face-src>
  </font-face>
</font>
<text x="10" y="10" font-weight="bold" font-size="75" fill="#3ABDF2" font-family="Amaranth">The tree</text>
  
 <path class="except" fill="#3E6325" d="m1175 917.29c-11.44-1.847-21.576 0.042-32.652 2.825-3.182 0.8-6.644 1.598-10.131 1.985 48.901-29.163 .....continued"
     fill="#639357"
     id="path5022" /><path
     d="m604.1 171.56s-18.18-9.487-18.989-9.087c-0.812 0.401-2.108 1.365-0.619 2.624 1.491 1.259 18.873 8.725 20.208 8.689 1.331-0.037 1.5-1.57-0.6-2.226z"
     fill="#3E6325"
     stroke="#A64F2C"
     stroke-miterlimit="10"
     id="path5024" />
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/paulfadams/pen/PRzMNE?editors=1111

Comment: you have not added https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js

Comment: Do you have some error in browser console?

Comment: Please note the code is too long to work in snippet. Please click the link to codepen instead.

Comment: Hi Aakanksh, Yes that library is loading in WP.

Comment: Just saying "it's not working" isn't really enough information. Does the tree load, but the click animation is not functioning? is it not loading at all? are there any error messages? what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: !function(a,b){function c(){function a(){"undefined"!=typeof _wpmejsSettings&&(c=b.extend(!0,{},_wpmejsSettings)),c.classPrefix="mejs-",c.success=c.success||function(a){var b,c;a.rendererName&&-1!==a.rendererName.indexOf("flash")&&(b=a.attributes.autoplay&&"false"!==a.attributes.autoplay,c=a.attributes.loop&&"false"!==a.attributes.loop,b&&a.addEventListener("canplay",function(){a.play()},!1),c&&a.addEventListener("ended",function(){a.play()},!1))},c.customError=function(a,b)

Comment: {if(-1!==a.rendererName.indexOf("flash")||-1!==a.rendererName.indexOf("flv"))return'<a href="'+b.src+'">'+mejsL10n.strings["mejs.download-video"]+"</a>"},b(".wp-audio-shortcode, .wp-video-shortcode").not(".mejs-container").filter(function(){return!b(this).parent().hasClass("mejs-mediaelement")}).mediaelementplayer(c)}var c={};return{initialize:a}}a.wp=a.wp||{},a.wp.mediaelement=new c,b(a.wp.mediaelement.initialize)}(window,jQuery);

Comment: Yes, Kuzenko, as above.

Comment: That's a PNG you've linked us to.

Comment: Yes,  Link0352, the tree loads, but the click animation is not functioning?  I tried changing the order that the JS files load in the web page.

Comment: spacer GIF, I placed that as It won't accept a svg file there. Please view the codepen link.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue once.

WordPress ships with its own version of the jQuery library.

Try using "jQuery" instead of just "$" sign.

For example: 
var svg = $("#svg-container"); should be replaced with var svg = jQuery("#svg-container");

Comment: Console is saying jquery is not defined though.

Comment: the Q should be uppercase in jQuery, I believe. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery instead of the "$" sign. ex: `jQuery("#svg-container");`